# Get Page Name and Not Slug in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, codex

I am using the code below to get y name of my wordpress page.

```
$pagename = $post->post_name;
```

The problem is that I'm getting a slug.

I get "wedding-cakes" instead of "Wedding Cakes"

How do I get the name "Wedding Cakes"?

Comment: You should use post_title.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [Wordpress docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/$post) relating to the `$post` object, you will want to do this instead:

```
$pageName = $post->post_title;
```

Which will return the post title not the slug. The name actually refers to the slug. From the [wordpress docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/$post):

> post_title (string) The post's title.
>
> post_name (string) The post's
> slug.

Answer (score 0):

It's SIMPLE! Using the function bellow we get the name of the post and not the slug:

```
$thePageTitle = get_the_title();
```

You can add the code below to convert it to a slug:

```
$thePageSlug = sanitize_title($thePageTitle);
```

Problem Solved!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the property for the title of the post is 'post_title' so you want to use $post->post_title when the Wordpress $post object is available to you. If it is not then you can use global $post first before you access the property.